# Why is this jQuery unload event being executed immediately after load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, onbeforeunload, onunload

For some reason, the code in my unload event function below is run immediately when loaded instead of waiting to be unloaded. Why?

Here's a jsfiddle so you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dillydadally/hsj8xqtx/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="btn"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var popup = window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'Window Unload Test', 'width=500,height=500');

    $(popup).unload( function() {
        console.log("here");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because when you first create the window it's location is actually about:blank. That then unloads when the URL you specified is requested.

If you change your unload handler to `console.log(popup.document.location.href)` you'll see its still about:blank.

To mitigate this you might want to wait for the content to load before attaching the unload handler.

Comment: Do you have a code recommendation on how to wait for the content to load? If I put a load event handler in the same place, it does nothing. If I do a setTimeout, I can't guarantee the window is finished loading.